# Android NetworkSecurityConfig files in both application module and library module manifests possible?

Tags: android, security, android-manifest, android-network-security-config

I'm working on a library module which has its own network security config xml file, and this file is set to android:networksecurityconfig in application level of the Android Manifest file in the library module level.

I want to see if it is possible, for another developer of an app that uses my module, to have their own network security config file at their app level, and set it to the application level of their app's manifest file.

I've experienced manifest merger issues before with themes, and the usage of tools:replace to have the app's theme take precedence. But I don't think I can accept their(Android Studio's build error) suggested answer and use tools:replace for android:networksecurityconfig because I want my library module's to be in effect.

Which leads me to my question in the title. Alternatively, if same named resource files do merge, would the same named file on both app and module levels, each having different domains and pin-sets configured, be merged into one networksecurityconfig file for use universally throughout the app?

Comment: To answer my own question about same named resource files, it does work, but it will take the application module's version of network security config instead of my library module's so this is a no-go.